# About the characteristic polynomial and powers of its matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A_{3\times 3}$ be a matrix with the characteristic polynomial $f_A(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$, what is $f_{A^{-1}}(x)$?

The eigenvalues of $A$ are $1,2,3$ and since $Av=\lambda v$ then $A^{-1}v=\lambda^{-1} v$ so the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ are $1,\frac 1 2, \frac 1 3$ and therefore  $f_{A^{-1}}(x)=(x-1)(x-\frac 1 2)(x-\frac 1 3)$ ?

It just seems too easy, is this right?

Comment: Yes it is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is fine. You may want to mention/consider that your argument works because all eigenvalues are nonzero (and this in turn implies that $A$ is invertible).

How this works: if $A$ is invertible and $Av=\lambda v$ for nonzero $v$, then $\lambda\ne0$. If we multiply both sides on the left by $A^{-1}$ we get
$$
v=\lambda\,A^{-1}v.
$$
If we now divide both sides by $\lambda$, 
$$
\lambda^{-1} v=A^{-1}v.
$$

Comment: I saw that the statement $A^m v = \lambda ^m v$ is true only for $m \ge 0$, don't we need to prove that because $A$ is invertible then it works for $m<0$?

Comment: I don't know what statement you saw nor how it was justified. In any case, I added a few lines to the answer with the justification.